# php array in url from json

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, arrays

Here is what I want to do:

I have some json like this

```
  var foo = {
   format:"json",
   type:"test",
   id:"26443"
  };
```

and I awant to put that in a url like this

```
 'http://example.com/a:3:{s:6:"format";s:4:"json";s:4:"type";s:4:"test";s:2:"id";s:5:"26443";}'
```

which I will then put into ajax call but everything I have tried results in error 501 BAD URI could someone tell me how to do this

I've tried this
**EDIT:**

after looking again and alerting the results of this function it IS build the results correcty they just arrn't being used propler either by ajax or the browser

```
 function js_array_to_php_array(a) {
  var a_php = "";
  var total = 3;

  for (var key in a){
   total;
   a_php = a_php + "s:" + String(key).length  + ":\""  + String(key) + "\";s:" + String(a[key]).length  +  ":\"" + String(a[key])  + "\";";
  }
  a_php = "a:" + total +":{" + a_php + "}";
  return a_php;
 }
```

when I use http fox it get this back

```
 http://example.com/a:3:%7Bs:6:%22format%22;s:4:%22json%22;s:4:%22type%22;s:4:%test%22;s:2:%22id%22;s:5:%2226443%22;}
```

which i find odd because it ecodes everything but the last curly bracket

Comment: I had trouble in the past with URLs like `/a:` on a Windows machine running apache.  After a little research, it appeared that this was due to an old directory traversal attack -- apache was suspicious that the URL represented an attempt to access the A: drive directly.

Comment: @frank thats interesting but I don't think thats the problem I put the url I show in my browser and it works as expect I just can't seem to generate the url properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so as it turns out there is nothing wrong with the function js_array_to_php_array it did exactly as I needed it to the problem was that I needed to use JSONP instead of JSON when running my ajax call as I was going cross domain which also explains why the code worked in the url but not when I ran ajax

thank you all for your help

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use a "normal" query string?

```
http://example.com/?type=test&id=26443

$type = $_GET['type'];
$id   = $_GET['id'];
```

Unless I am missing something?

Comment: because this is what the url expects to see

Answer (score 2):

There is a jQuery function for this already! Use it and love it.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Comment: it doesn't look like this does exactly what I want could I keeps getting the word "object" in the string

Answer (score 0):

```
http://example.com/a:3:{s:6:"format";s:4:"json";s:4:"type";s:5:"test";s:2:"id";s:5:"26443";}
```

501 is right — that's not a valid URL. URLs definitely can't have quotes in them, or (for most part) curly brackets.

If you really have to submit a PHP literal structure in a URL without doing it as normal set of query parameters, you would have to URL-encode the invalid characters, which you can do like:

```
url= 'http://example.com/'+encodeURI(js_array_to_php_array(foo));
```

resulting in:

```
http://example.com/a:3:%7Bs:6:%22format%22;s:4:%22json%22;s:4:%22type%22;s:5:%22test%22;s:2:%22id%22;s:5:%2226443%22;%7D
```

incidentally this:

```
String(key)
```

is superfluous: object keys are always strings in JS, even if you put them in as numbers;

```
"\""  + String(a[key]) + "\""
```

is going to go wrong if the value can contain a quote or backslash, and

```
total;
```

there should surely be an increment here?

Answer (score 0):

On the PHP end, you could use `urlencode(json_encode($obj))` to convert an object to a string that can be used in a URL.

After I posted this, I realized you're trying to convert a JavaScript variable to a URL string after I saw `var foo = {`.  Duh.

Comment: that's in php. I need in javascript / jquery a php array put in url