# Json object to uri string in RESTful request (PHP)

Tags: php, json, web-services, url, rest

What is the proper way to pass ambiguous parameters in a REST request url?

`var requestObj = {

    city: 'London',

    taxes: [

  { name: 'Income Tax', value: '10%', 'applies_to': 'paycheck'},

  { name: 'Sales Tax', value: '7.5%', 'applies_to': 'sales'}

]

}`

How can I make that request to http://blah.com which will receive the request?

http://blah.com/city/london/taxes/**Now What?**

I have previously checked this
[php array in url from json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622855/php-array-in-url-from-json) and many more but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do here? If you're adding a new entry, then in a RESTful API you'd use a `POST` request. This means that the parameters won't even appear in the URL.

If this is some sort of query, you could maybe send the parameters base64 encoded. It's not elegant, it's not even strictly RESTful, but it should work unless the URL becomes too long.

**Edit:** You could define your own serialization for the taxes array, something like
`.../Income Tax/10%/paycheck/Sales Tax/7.5%/sales` (urlencoded, of course). Still not nice, but this and some kind of encoding (like base64) are the only things I can think of.

Comment: Make a request to an API that calculates Sales and Income tax.

Comment: I see. The first paragraph doesn't apply then, sorry about that.